# Notation question: bigraded direct sum of graded objects

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, notation

In some work I'm doing I have two graded modules $M$ and $N$ (graded on $\mathbb Z$, say) and need to take, not the usual direct sum, but the bigraded sum consisting of all $M_p \oplus N_q$ (so graded on $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$). For the graded sum I would simply write $M\oplus N$. Before I make up a notation for the bigraded sum, is there an already existing notation that anyone has used or seen?

I'm not sure what tags to include on this question, feel free to criticize. I've tried to tag the communities that might have run into this before.

Comment: I would denote this $\boxtimes$, the external tensor product. If you treat graded objects as weight decomposition of some $\mathbb{G}_m$ action, then this bigraded sum is indeed the external tensor product of two representations of $\mathbb{G}_m$ as a representation of $\mathbb{G}_m \times \mathbb{G}_m$. I don't know if anyone have used this notation, though.